# Image of a Linear Transformation $T_A: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am struggling to find the image of a linear transformation $T_A: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, given as $T_Av=Av,$ where $v\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $A$ is the matrix,

\begin{pmatrix}x^2&x\sqrt{1-x^2}\\ 
x\sqrt{1-x^2}&1-x^2\end{pmatrix}

I have found the kernel to be the zero vector, $0_\mathbb{R^2}$. Something suspicious is going on with this matrix, and I'm not sure what/how to describe it. I believe the image would be some line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ but I am unsure. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is $x\in\mathbb{R}$ just an arbitrary constant? If so, then assuming $\text{ker}T_A=0$, and knowing the domain and codomain have the same dimension, the rank-nullity theorem says that $T_A$ is an isomorphism and its image is all of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: For any $x$ the determinant is $0$. So the image is a line.

Comment: If you multiply the first row by $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and the second row by $x$ you get a matrix with two identical rows. this gives a nontrivial linear combination of the rows that sums to $0$, so the kernel must be nontrivial.

Comment: Hint: Let $x = a$ and $b = \sqrt{1-x^2}$ and see if that makes anything stand out

Comment: Thank you! I thought so, but I was unsure of myself (as usual) and needed to hear it from someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for $|x|\le 1$

$$\det\begin{pmatrix}x^2&x\sqrt{1-x^2}\\ 
x\sqrt{1-x^2}&1-x^2\end{pmatrix}=x^2(1-x^2)-x^2(1-x^2)=0$$

therefore kernel is not zero indeed the RREF is

$$\begin{pmatrix}x^2&x\sqrt{1-x^2}\\ 
x\sqrt{1-x^2}&1-x^2\end{pmatrix}\to \begin{pmatrix}x^2\sqrt{1-x^2}&x(1-x^2)\\ 
x^2\sqrt{1-x^2}&x(1-x^2)\end{pmatrix}\to \begin{pmatrix}x^2\sqrt{1-x^2}&x(1-x^2)\\ 
0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

therefore a basis for the kernel is given by $(\sqrt{1-x^2},-x)$, which works also for the limit case $|x|=1$.